# Best way to integrate with Azure AD for adding users to group

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a user to a group. Currently I'm just using postman I was planning on moving this into a java app that is pulling HR data and putting adding the users/groups into AD. It appears that the Microsoft Graph API I was using is no longer allowing this Per the documentation I found below: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupID}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupID%7D)

Microsoft Graph API users after October 5 2020 can no longer use the Users API to get and set properties associated with User objects in Azure AD.

Is there any API or other connection I can make to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The documentation for Graph API still lists the user- group add operation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create user/create group and then add the user to group then for creating the user/group you can use the below:

[Create User - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Create group - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-create-a-microsoft-365-group)

If the User is already present in the Azure active directory , then you can use the user object ID and add the member using the below:

[Add member - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

I tested it using postman the above three operations and the outputs are as below:

**Create Group:**

[image]

**Create User:**

[image]

**Adding the newly created user to the newly created group:**

[image]

**From azure portal:**

[image]

Comment: I keep getting the following error. I've compared your screen shots to mine and it looks the same. {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration.","innerError":{"date":"2021-09-28T14:05:24"

Comment: Hello @skigdmg, could you please share the body and header details of the request

Comment: And as per the error you shared it says that you are applying for on-premises directory sync objects or active directory objects which are undergoing migration . May I know if that is a case in you environment

Comment: You can refer this if you do have a hybrid directory then you have to add group or users from on-premises which will be synced with azure ad .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/106279/getting-34unable-to-update-the-specified-propertie.html